# Não estou conseguindo iterar o array

Tags: node.js, api, express.js, async-await, array-push

Eu gostaria de popular   esse array com o objeto category que obtenho quando faço a query `findById`. Mas a variável  `loggedUserCategories` aparece como um array vazio na response , entretanto, eu consigo visualizar os `console.log(category);`

```
        let loggedUserCategories = [];

        
        categoriesId.forEach(async(id) => {
            
            const category =  await CategoryModel.findById(id);
            loggedUserCategories.push(category)
            console.log(category);

        });

      res.send(loggedUserCategories);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código não tem diferença nenhuma com o código abaixo:

```
let loggedUserCategories = [];
res.send(loggedUserCategories);
categoriesId.forEach(async(id) => {
    const category =  await CategoryModel.findById(id);
    loggedUserCategories.push(category)
    console.log(category);
});
```

Tente assim:

```
async () => {
    let loggedUserCategories = [];
    categoriesId.forEach(async (id) => {
        const category = await CategoryModel.findById(id);
        loggedUserCategories.push(category)
        console.log(category);
    });
    res.send(loggedUserCategories);
}
```

Ou esperando as promises que cada await cria:

```
let loggedUserCategories = [];
const promises = categoriesId.map(async (id, idx) => {
    category = await CategoryModel.findById(id);
    loggedUserCategories.push(category);
    console.log(category);
});
await Promise.all(promises);
res.send(loggedUserCategories);
```